# get latest row using order by and string primary key

Tags: mysql

i have database table like this ( idnumber, id_transaction is varchar)

```
----------------------------------------------
|  idnumber  |    date    |  id_transaction  |
----------------------------------------------
| 12312312   | 2020-03-14 |        s1        |
| 12312312   | 2020-03-14 |        s9        |
| 12312312   | 2020-03-15 |        s13       |
| 12312312   | 2020-03-15 |        s14       |
----------------------------------------------
```

i have this query from my script

```
select * from transaksi where idnumber='12312312' order by date and REPLACE(id_transaction, "s", "") DESC LIMIT 1
```

when i run it, i get "s9" result whereas i want to get "s14" result, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for the ORDER BY clause:

```
select * from transaksi 
where idnumber='12312312' 
order by date desc, REPLACE(id_transaction, 's', '') + 0 desc limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2x4LEZw7P7aFdmeAeed7Su/0).
Results:

```
| idnumber | date       | id_transaction |
| -------- | -----------| -------------- |
| 12312312 | 2020-03-15 | s14            |
```